# Unity Dependency is not working page to presenter in web forms

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, webforms, unity-container, mvp

I am updating the old web forms project which is working on the MVP model. While refactoring that into the layered project I started DI using unity.

I have a below files with my new DI, but in my Presenter parameterized constructor is not called and ObjView is returning null. How can I fix this error

```
IUsersView
{

    int UserID { get; set; }
    List<UsersModel> oPTList { get; set; }
    //Have only few methods
}
```

and i have page shown below

```
Users(.aspx.cs) : System.Web.UI.Page, IUsersView
 {
   UserPresenter obj = null; //Old code
   IUserPresenter _userPresenter = null;
   public readonly IUsersView _userView;
   public readonly IUser _user;

   public User(IUser user,
            IUserPresenter userPresenter)
    {
        _user= user;
        _userPresenter = userPresenter;

    }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try{
           obj = new UserPresenter(this, _projectUpload); //Old Code 
           obj.CheckLoginUserExist(usrLoginID, usrName); //Old Code 
           _UserPresenter.CheckLoginUserExist(usrLoginID, usrName); // New Code with DI
        }
    }
 }
```

and Presenter code

```
public class UserPresenter : IUserPresenter
{
        IUserView objView;
        IUser _user= null;
        public UserPresenter()
        {

        }

        public UserPresenter(IUserView view, IUser user)
        {
            objView = view;
            _user = user;
        }
        public void CheckLoginUserExist(int usrLoginID, string usrName)
        {
            objView.oPTList = objBL.GetUserRoles(usrLoginID,usrName); //Old Code and i am getting date from DAL layer
            objView.GetUserRoles(); //Old Code
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this, it looks like you have defined your interface incorrectly.

```
Users(.aspx.cs) : System.Web.UI.Page, IUsersView
 {
   IUserPresenter _userPresenter;

   public readonly IUsersView _userView;
   public readonly IUser _user;

   public User(IUser user,
            IUserPresenter userPresenter)
    {
        _User = user;
        _userPresenter= userPresenter;

    }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try{
           obj = new UserPresenter(this, _projectUpload); //Old Code 
           obj.CheckLoginUserExist(usrLoginID, usrName); //Old Code 
           _userPresenter.CheckLoginUserExist(usrLoginID, usrName); // New Code with DI
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry my bad while editing in StackOverflow the code I missed it. still, it's now working

Comment: Looks like my presenter parameterized constructor is not called and ObjView is returning null.. how can I call that from my page not initializing the new object like old code

Comment: remove the empty constructor

Comment: For that empty constructor.. few other methods are dependent on it